# How to convert number to date in sql

Tags: python, sql, oracle, date, type-conversion

I am fetching data from oracle using sql in python. There are columns having integer values. I want to convert those column values to dates while retrieving data.

```py
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user, pwd, dsn, encoding="UTF-8")
cursor = connection.cursor()
results = cursor.execute("SELECT TO_DATE(DATECREATED,'yyyymmdd') as DATECREATED from ARADMIN.EPM_TechnicianInformation").fetchall()
```

It's not working.

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? Because, e.g.`select to_date(20210929, 'yyyymmdd') from dual;` returns correct result because `20210929` represents valid "date" in `yyyymmdd` format.

Comment: I want to use actual table name instead dual to convert column values directly into date. the above query is giving me errors  - DatabaseError: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: I'm just saying that query works OK if value you pass to it represents a valid date value. **Of course** you'd use your own table. As of error you got: not all values have valid dates. As Oracle complains about **invalid month**, you have something like 2021**15**29 - there's no month whose number is 15. That's what happens when people store dates as strings or numbers, because database can't do any validation for you. Now you'll have to find those invalid "dates" and fix them first.

Answer (score 0):

> the above query is giving me errors - DatabaseError:
>
> ```
> ORA-01843: not a valid month
> ```

From Oracle 12, you can add a clause to handle errors during conversion due to invalid data:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(
         DATECREATED
         DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
         'yyyymmdd'
       ) as DATECREATED
FROM   ARADMIN.EPM_TechnicianInformation
```

Which for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ARADMIN.EPM_TechnicianInformation ( datecreated ) AS
SELECT 20210929 FROM DUAL UNION ALL  -- A valid date
SELECT 20211301 FROM DUAL;           -- An invalid date as month = 13
```

Outputs:

> | DATECREATED |
> | --- |
> | 2021-09-29 00:00:00 |
> | *<null>* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=81470bce353c71307c4d57c175da0a89)*